# SpringMVC, how can I configure SLL in servlet beans?

Tags: spring

I am trying to learn a jdbc connection project according to this site suggested. (https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-crud-example).

So far I have got the index page running, and my inputed info is POSTed to my MySQL database(so I somehow assume my connection to database is successful).

However, when i try to viewemp(READ) as suggested on this tutorial, my page could not capture the employee info(the jsp file to display employee info shows, but no data). This is the error log I got.

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
STACKTRACE:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

Google seems to be suggesting this is an SSL problem and suggested I should create a application.property file to set up SSL.

is it possible to alter my bean setting in my servlet.xml file setting instead?

```
<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<!-- 1. Register JDBC Driver class -->
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<!-- 2. establish connection -->
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatpoint" />
<property name="username" value="root" />
<property name="password" value="********" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fixed this error

1. Turn off use of SSL by passing extra variable ?useSSL=false

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" name="dataSource">
  <!--<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />-->
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatpoint?useSSL=false" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="******" />
</bean>
```

1. You can also configure it in your mysql database using my.ini file

[Edit 17-11-2022]
If you only wanted to setup self-signed ssl certificate, then Setting up HTTPS for Spring Boot requires two steps:

Generated Self Signed Certificate

1. Open Terminal (JDK 11, comes with utility)

```
// generate JKS keystore:
keytool -genkeypair -alias <project-name> -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -storetype JKS -keystore <generatedfilename.jks> -validity 3650 -storepass <password>

// generate PKCS12 keystore
keytool -genkeypair -alias <project-name> -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore <generatedfilename.p12> -validity 3650 -storepass password
```

Setting up with spring-boot properties file (src/main/resources/application.properties)

```
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: <password>
server.ssl.key-store-type: pkcs12
server.ssl.key-alias: <project-name>
server.ssl.key-password: <password>
```